# What’s my best move here?

Tags: analysis

I ask regarding for this position below.

```
[Title "White to move"]
[fen "5r1r/1p6/p1p2p2/2P1bPpk/4R3/6PP/P2B2K1/3R4 w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Whose move is it? Are you white or black?

Comment: guess its white to move Rh4 and g4

Comment: @cmgchess, very nice! Let it be an "ANSWER".

Comment: I could write an answer but I feel too lazy since it was only a two moves mate

Answer (score 2):

If you put this position into an engine it shows that white has a forced mate in 2

```
[fen "5r1r/1p6/p1p2p2/2P1bPpk/4R3/6PP/P2B2K1/3R4 w - - 0 1"]


1. Rh4 gxh4 2. g4#
```